# AWS Neptune transaction support

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune

Neptune currently supports only OLTP type of graph traversal queries?

But from [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/access-graph-gremlin-differences.html):

> Transactions
> Neptune opens a new transaction at the beginning of each Gremlin traversal and closes the transaction upon the successful completion of the traversal. The transaction is rolled back when there is an error.
>
> **Multiple statements separated by a semicolon (;) or a newline character (\n) are included in a single transaction.** Every statement other than the last must end with a next() step to be executed. Only the final traversal data is returned.
>
> Manual transaction logic using tx.commit() and tx.rollback() is not supported.

Multiple statements separated by semicolon or newline are executed in a single transaction. So, can you execute multiple queries per transaction? For example multiple .drop() queries in a single script?

```
g.V().has(id,'1').drop();
g.V().has(id,'2').drop();
```

By trying the above, only the last query is executed (only the vertex with id='2' is deleted).

But for adding vertices, it works:

```
g.addV('item').property(id,'3').next()";
g.addV('item').property(id,'4').next()";
```

Both vertices are added.

Is there any support for multiple delete queries in a single transaction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just a guess, but I think you might need to `iterate()` your traversals, thus:

```
g.V().has(id,'1').drop().iterate();
g.V().has(id,'2').drop().iterate();
```

Given your example with `addV()` and the behavior that your'e seeing with `drop()` the last traversal is the only one that is auto-iterated, which is consistent with how Gremlin Server would typically process script requests. I'm guessing that Neptune will work in the same fashion.

Comment: Thanks! It worked. I had wrongly tried with .next() in the end. 
From documentation:
`iterate() does not exactly fit the definition of a terminal step in that it doesn’t return a result, but still returns a traversal - it does however behave as a terminal step in that it iterates the traversal and generates side effects without returning the actual result.`